# How to perform appbar back button click action without changing default icon

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my application there is some action,that I needed to perform in AppBar back button.
My issue is, I want to use default back button with my click action.

So its possible to do this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```dart
appBar: AppBar(
        leading: BackButton(
          onPressed: (){
            print("back Pressed");
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I want my own navigation action.not back action perform

Comment: ah now i got your point, so you need to override the onClick method of the back button in the appbar?

Comment: yes, I need my own action. Not back navigation

Comment: I edited the answer to match your question

Comment: Ok,I will check this and revert you.

Answer (score 0):

```
appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Do your thing..
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              title: Text("Your Text"),
              centerTitle: true,
```

I hope that answers..